# Protection of a dns server

Tags: domain-name-system, security, bind

I recently started to host my own domains on my servers. I can already see a fair bit of bogus queries arriving to my servers. Some dns amplification attacks, etc. What can I do in order to further improve the safety of my dns servers?

Comment: Disabling recursion would be one step to take.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that this is an authoritative-only nameserver (the question makes it sound like that is the case), I would suggest the following:

- Ensure that recursion is disabled or at least not allowed for the general public. (Allowing recursion will just attract unnecessary abuse.)
- Enable [response rate limiting](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.9/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#id2588961). (Rate limiting the responses to "spammed" queries will make you less attractive as the reflector in an amplification attack.)